# Physical LAN not working over switch, but wireless LAN is

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan, switch

I have connected two computers over a switch. The desktop computer is running Linux Mint 17.3 and the laptop windows 7.

The Desktop only has an IPv6 address for the physical LAN. Laptop has both IPv4 and IPv6.

The laptop can ping the physical lan IP6 address of the desktop, but not the other way around (either IPv4/IPv6).

However both computers are also connected to a router (mobile hotspot) and have wireless IPs.

When using that IP the desktop IS able to ping the laptop (and vice versa).

All firewalls are off on both PCs and the windows PC has network discovery turned on.

My switch is a simple DLINK 8-p Nway switch. Bought maybe 7-8 years ago and has all lights on and blinking (indicating network traffic).

The Windows laptop is on a separate workgroup. Is this a problem and how can I change it if it is?

How can I make the physical LAN work as well?

More info, from desktop to laptop I get this:

traceroute `169.254.222.249`

```
traceroute to 169.254.222.249 (169.254.222.249), 64 hops max

  1.   192.168.1.1  1.551ms  1.544ms  1.467ms 
  2.   /*  *  * 
  3.   10.117.2.172  31.545ms  30.846ms  44.478ms 
  4.   /* * *
  5.   /* * *
  6.   /* * *
  7.   (Forever)
```

Comment: If machine A can ping machine B, that means communication is working in both directions. If you can't ping in the other direction, it's likely just because machine A is not configured to respond to such pings.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can I check this somehow or enable it?

Comment: Is there some specific reason you need ping replies? You already know communication is working in both directions, since both the ping from A to B went through and the reply from B to A went through. So what is there to check or enable exactly?

Comment: Pings should work because I'm able to ping the wifi IP address.
I don't need them, but it seems to cause problems so LAN games don't work.

Comment: You know pings work. If A can ping B, that means both the ping and the reply went through.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is that enable IP4 on your windows 7 laptop. Are you trying to test something with IPv6? you need to make sure IPv4 is working first before testing IPv6 within your network.

First, Assign static IP address with correct default gateway to both PC and laptop rather then dynamic IP (If you have DHCP).

Disconnect your laptop and computer from mobile hotspot (let's test physical LAN port first as they might become conflicted if you have both wifi and physical LAN connected).

Your both computer and laptops are connected to your switch. On this switch, you also need a router which is your default gateway but you did not mention what router you have in your question.

Your network should be something like this to make them communicate each other.
For example, 
Laptop- IP: 192.168.0.10 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 DG: 192.168.0.1

Desktop - IP: 192.168.0.11 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 DG: 192.168.0.1

Router (Default Gateway) IP: 192.168.0.1 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

You should still be able to ping to another workgroup as long as they are in the same network.

Comment: Actually I messed up one sentence, it was the DESKTOP that has only IP6.

I don't have a router, just a mobile hotspot, but it seems to act as one giving wifi LAN also. (Sorry if that has nothing to do with a router I'm not a network expert)

I tried assigning an IP manually on both computers, but neither of those can be pinged - only the IP6 address of the desktop can be pinged from the laptop.

Comment: (I just want to be able to join a LAN game between the two computers using the switch.)

Comment: @MartinClemensBloch Why does the desktop only feature IPv6?

Comment: @benjaminS I don't know, I tried adding an IPv4 address manually, but I could not ping it unlike the IP6 one.

Answer (score 0):

To get to your target (play a game with two directly attached computers) just set them both up with a static IP. They won't have internet, but they will be able to communicate with each other.  If you want to share the mobile hotspot internet between the two and only one of them has Wi-Fi, enable internet connection sharing on the one with Wi-Fi.